# Button with hidden input

Tags: javascript, css, animation, button

I want to create a button with a hidden input that activates once the button was pressed.
I made demo but in this demo input animated via changing width and padding which is not good.

So is there any better way to animate this button?

HTML:

```
<div class="button-wrap">
  <label>Max score</label>
  <input>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .button-wrap {
    display: flex;
    height: var(--height);
    outline: none;
    --height: 20px;
    --padding: 5px;
    --background: #454555;
    --background-active: #46467c;
    --background-hover: #46467c;
    --separator: #565666;
    --radius: 5px;
    --input-width: 30px;
    --text-color: #eee;
  }

  input, label {
    height: auto;
    transition: .3s;
    outline: 0;
    color: var(--text-color);
    text-align: center;
  }

  label {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    padding: var(--padding);
    border-radius: var(--radius);
    background-color: var(--background);
    border-color: var(--separator);
    transition: border-radius .5s;
    user-select: none;
    text-align: center;
  }

  input {
    padding: var(--padding) 0;
    border: none;
    width: 0;
    background-color: var(--background);
    border-radius: 0 var(--radius) var(--radius) 0;
  }

  .button-wrap:hover label,
  .button-wrap:hover input {
    background-color: var(--background-hover);
  }

  .button-wrap[active] label {
    border-radius: var(--radius) 0 0 var(--radius);
    background-color: var(--background-active);
    border-color: var(--separator);
    border-right: 2px solid var(--separator);
    transition: border-radius .3s;
  }

  .button-wrap[active] input {
    width: calc(var(--input-width) - 2 * var(--padding));
    background-color: var(--background-active);
    padding: var(--padding);
  }
```

Attribute 'active' is added by js after the button was pressed.

And there is the demo:
[image: button with hidden input]

Comment: In my humble opinion, it looks really elegant. You can animate the opacity of your input element so that the layout wouldn't be altered when the button clicked.

Comment: @SerdarSayın, thanks, but I would like to stick to [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing) and avoid animate width and padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's the answer that my teacher came up with.

HTML

```
<div class='button-wrap'>
  <label>Max count</label>
  <input>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button-wrap {
  width: 200px;
  contain: content;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: #454555;
  --input-width: 32px;
}
.button-wrap[active] {
  background-color: #46467c;
}
.button-wrap:hover {
  background-color: #46467c;
}

input, label {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: transform .3s;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  color: #eee;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 5px;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 2px solid #565666;
  width: var(--input-width);
  transform: translateX(var(--input-width));
}

.button-wrap[active] label {
  transform: translateX(calc(-1 * var(--input-width) / 2));
}
.button-wrap[active] input {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Here's the [demo](https://codepen.io/demiler/pen/dyMNNGP)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  e.toggleAttribute("active").toggle;
}
```

```css
.button-wrap {
    display: flex;
    outline: none;
    --height: 20px;
    --padding: 5px;
    --background: #47478d;
    --background-active: #46464f;
    --background-hover: #46467c;
    --separator: #565666;
    --radius: 5px;
    --input-width: 40px;
    --text-color: #eee;
    width: 250px;
    height: 40px;
    background:#34344d;
    padding:15px;
  }

  input, label {
    height: auto;
    outline: 0;
    color: var(--text-color);
    text-align: center;
  }

  label {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding: var(--padding);
    border-radius: var(--radius);
    background-color: var(--background);
    border-color: var(--separator);
    transition: border-radius .5s;
    user-select: none;
    text-align: center;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
  }

  input {
    padding: var(--padding);
    border: none;
    width: calc(var(--input-width) - 2 * var(--padding));
    background-color: var(--background);
    border-radius: 0 var(--radius) var(--radius) 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: display 0ms 400ms, opacity 400ms 0ms;
  }

  .button-wrap:hover label,
  .button-wrap:hover input {
    background-color: var(--background-hover);
  }

  .button-wrap[active] label {
    border-radius: var(--radius) 0 0 var(--radius);
    background-color: var(--background-active);
    border-color: var(--separator);
    border-right: 2px solid var(--separator);
    transition: border-radius .3s;
  }

  .button-wrap[active] input {
    background-color: var(--background-active);
    padding: var(--padding);
    color:#fff;
    opacity: 1;
    display:block;
    transition: display 0ms 0ms, opacity 600ms 0ms;
  }
```

```html
<div class="button-wrap" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <label>Max score</label>
  <input type="text" value="100">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but it's still using `width` and `padding` for the animation which is not good. :(

Comment: Ok let check now :)

Comment: Animating width and padding is fine, don't know why you want to limit yourself so much?

Comment: @dantheman93 it's not [recommended](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing)

Comment: I was also thinking about whether it's unnecessary or not but it recommends avoiding "large" layout changing. Yours is way too small to be a burden for your application.

Comment: that is only for large changes that affect the entire page. A small button is nothing.

Comment: I think it can be done by css translate to achieve this?

Comment: @RayeesAC, yep, I've tried it but input was taking space inside of wrap while the button was inactive which was looking odd.

Comment: @RayeesAC It also looks odd https://codepen.io/demiler/pen/VwaPKvz